# Ajax PHP + MySQL registration form tutorial

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Until now I have
HTML

```
<form id="account_reg" action="reg.php" method="post">
    <div id="response"></div>
    <div class="input">
      <label>Login</>
      <input name="login" type="text" class="required" id="login" size="30"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
    <label>Password</>
    <input name="password" type="text" class="required" id="password" size="30"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
    <label>Repeat Password</>
    <input name="rpassword" type="text" class="required" id="rpassword" size="30"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
    <label>Email</>
    <input name="email" type="text" class="required" id="email" size="30"/>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
    <input type="hidden" name="honeypot" id="honeypot" value="http://"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="humancheck" id="humancheck" class="clear" value=""/>
    </div>
</form>
```

MY PHP
I have some validation on server side.
`

```
include("dop/config.php"); //includ Db connect

    $login = ($_POST['login']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $rpassword = ($_POST['rpassword']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
    $honeypot = $_POST['honeypot']; 
if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) { 
$error_message = '';
$reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-Za-Z.](2,4)$/";
if(!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)){
$error_message .="<p>A Valid email is required</p>";
}
if(empty($login)){
$error_message .="<p>enter login</p>";
}
if(empty($password)){
$error_message .="<p>Enter password</p>";
}
if(empty($rpassword)){
$error_message .="<p>Enter password again</p>";
}
if($password != $rpassword){
$error_message .="<p>password mut match</p>";
}
} 
else {
$return['error'] = true;
$return['msg'] = "<h3>There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.</h3>";    
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

My JS
With Validation.

```
$('#send').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var valid = '';
        var required =' is required.';
        var login = $('#account_reg #login').val();
        var password = $('#account_reg #password').val();
        var rpassword = $('#account_reg #rpassword').val();
        var email = $('#account_reg #email').val();
        var honeypot = $('#account_reg #honeypot').val();
        var humancheck = $('#account_reg #humancheck').val();

        if(login = ''){
            valid ='<p> Your Name '+ required +'</p>';
        }
        if(password='' || company.length<=6){
            valid +='<p> Password '+ required +'</p>';
        }
        if(rpassword != password){
            valid +='<p> password must match </p>';
        }
        if(!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i))
        {
            valid +='<p> Your Email' + required +'</p>';
        }


        if (honeypot != 'http://') {
            valid += '<p>Spambots are not allowed.</p>';    
        }

        if (humancheck != '') {
            valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>'; 
        }
        if(valid !=''){
            $('#account_reg #response').removeClass().addClass("error")
                .html('<strong> Please Correct the errors Below </strong>' + valid).fadeIn('fast');
        }
        else{
            //$('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing...').fadeIn('fast');
            var formData = $('#account_reg').serialize();
            $('#send').val("Please wait...");
            submitForm(formData);
        }
    });
function submitForm(formData) {

$.post('reg2.php',formData, function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    $('#send').val("Send");
    if (data === '1') {
        alert('ok!');
    } else {
        alert('wrong shit');
    }
});
};
```

I didn't do yet the MySQL part With Inserting and checking if account is already registered.

The first problem that I have is on Click event redirects me on reg.php even when I use `e.preventDefault();`

If anybody knows a good tutorial for creating registration form or any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is submitted, that is why you get to reg.php. From what I see you are submitting the data with a custom function anyway so the quickest way to fix that would be to change the submit input into a regular button. So

```
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send"/>
```

becomes

```
<input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Send"/>
```

I think that it might also help if you return false when you find an error in the function that validates the form when.

A side question: I find it strange that you chose to have a honeypot field with a value (http://). Usually those fields are empty.. Is there any specific reason for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep all your `JS` code expect `function submitForm(formData)` inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

If I'm not wrong there is no variable with name `company` so change this variable to `password` i,e. in second `if condition` of your validation.

Note: If some errors exist in your code then don't escape from those errors instead try to debug it.

Comment: Yeah sorry In my code it is in DOM ready.
I change the company. But still on click is redirecting me to reg.php

Comment: @Froxz: Remember one thing if your problem is not solved then don't accept any answer by this you only lose new responses to your question.Then coming to your bug, if some bugs exist in your `click` function then `form` will submit,cross check your `javascript` console for any errors is exist.

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong with JS code when the code is not working

maybe you can try from this example for SignupForm using JQuery http://bit.ly/1aAXy5U